# Message text unavailable. Resource file not found

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce

I am developing a Windows CE 6.0 application using VB.Net. I almost completed my application but the problem is that when I run my application on the device error detail will not be displayed. I have kept a separate error log file which contains all the detail of the error. But whenever error occurs the text file contains:

> "Message text unavailable . resource file microsoft.visual basic not found."

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

try

'here is my code

Catch ex As Exception

FileName = "\Application Data\Error_" & Format(Now, "yyyyddMM").ToString & ".txt"

```
        If File.Exists(FileName) = False Then
            objwriter = File.CreateText(FileName)
            objwriter.WriteLine(Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:mm:ss").ToString() & " " & ex.Message)
            objwriter.Close()

        Else
            objwriter = File.AppendText(FileName)
            objwriter.WriteLine(Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:mm:ss").ToString() & " " & ex.Message)
            objwriter.Close()

        End If
        sqlstatus.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Try
```

Comment: add the code for writing to the log file to the question.

Comment: I solved this. i just re installed my .net ce 3.5 framework on the device.